Android Jetpack Compose drawArc brush custom radii of ends
I am trying to draw a speedometer in a compose canvas.
drawArc(
              brush = Brush.verticalGradient(gradientColors),
              startAngle = 135f,
              sweepAngle = 270f,
              useCenter = false,
              topLeft = topLeftOffset,
              size = arcRectSize,
              style = Stroke(
                  width = strokeWidth,
                  cap = StrokeCap.Round
              )
          )

works fine, but I want to have a smaller radius of the StrokeCap to achieve following arc with smooth ends:
Is this with onboard methods possible?

